# Long gridded list: recycler vs gridview

Tags: android, list, gridview, android-recyclerview

I want to make a list of square objects. The list should have 3 columns, and will have very many rows, more than 300. My question is: should I use grid view or recycler? I have read the recycler is more optimised.

IF RECYCLER (with grid layout manager):
Do I have to set up the cards to be one third of the width of the recycler, (To fit the columns) or does the recycler do that itself? I have found the documentation to be very unhelpful in this regard.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RecyclerView is preferable as it is a newer widget with modular design, where you can plug in different layout managers. It also enforces using a ViewHolder for better view reuse.

For your particular case, use a GridLayoutManager, which defaults to equal columns. If you want different spans for your cells, you can change the behaviour using a GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup.